# Subtracting all elements in single array Java

Tags: java, arrays

Hi I'm having trouble subtracting one array element to the next element to get the correct answer. The value of the array are given by the user.

Example:
If the user wants to input 3 numbers which are 10, 8, 1
10-8-1 = 1

```
int numberOT = 0;
int total =0;
System.out.println("Enter Number of times: ");
numberOT =in.nextInt();

int number[] = new int [numberOT];



for(int i = 0; i<numberOT; i++)
{
    System.out.println("Enter Number: ");
    number[i] = in.nextInt();
}
for(int t =0; t<number.length-1; t++)
{
  total = number[t] - number[t+1];
}
System.out.println("total: " + total);
```

Comment: Initialize `total = number[0]`, start the loop at `t=1`, `total -= number[t];`.

Answer (score 0):

Change the 2nd loop to this:

```java
total = number[0];
for (int i=1; i<number.length; i++) {
    total -= number[i];
}
```

You want to subtract the remaining array items from the first one. Therefore `total` in the beginning should be equal to the first item and in the loop subtract each consequent (start from the index `1`) item from the `total`.

Remember the number of items in the array must be equal to or larger than 2.

Comment: I tried your solution but the answer still wrong. I run the program the output for 10-8-1 is -9

Comment: @Gian did you start the loop at 1 or are you still starting it at zero?

Answer (score 0):

this line is totally wrong : `total = number[t] - number[t+1];` as in the last loop

**total = number[1] - number[2]** which will be equivalent to **total = 8 - 1 = 7** which is totally wrong because you have to accumulate the total variable .

so as mentioned above the full correct answer code is :

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Main
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

            int numberOT = 0;
            int total =0;
            System.out.println("Enter Number of times: ");
            numberOT =in.nextInt();

            int number[] = new int [numberOT];

            for(int i = 0; i<numberOT; i++)
            {
                System.out.println("Enter Number: ");
                number[i] = in.nextInt();
            }
            total = number[0];
            for (int i=1; i<number.length; i++) {
                total = total - number[i];
            }
            System.out.println("total: " + total);

        }
    }
```

and here is image of the output:

[[image]][1]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one liner (computation wise) using streams. Take the first element, stream the array skipping the first element and subtract the sum of the remaining.

```
int[] arr = { 10, 8, 3, 1 };
int sum = arr[0] - IntStream.of(arr).skip(1).sum();
System.out.println(sum);
```

But no matter how you do it, you have the potential for `int` overflow or underflow depending on the size of your values and the length of the array.